# jmespath query on aws-shell

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jmespath, aws-shell

I need to extract, from AWS CLOUDFORMATION, all the stacks that contain, within the name, a specific string.
I use the following command from aws-shell

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --query "Stacks[?contains(StackName, 'STRING_A')][StackName,StackId]" --output text | tr '\t' ';'
```

and I'm able to extract all the info that I need.

The problem is that I need to search also another string (suppose STRING_B)...What is the correct command? How can I insert an OR condition into the "?contains" ?

I made several attempts, but none has been successful.

e.g.

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --query "Stacks[?contains(StackName, 'STRING_A'||'STRING_B')][StackName,StackId]" --output text | tr '\t' ';'
```

but this solution extract only the records that satisfy the first condition (STRING_A)

For my application, instead of "contain" I can also use "ends_with".....the problem/question is the same :-)

I appreciate your help, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Context

- Jmespath query on AWS shell

### Problem

- How to specify `or-expression` over a string-contains query

### Solution

- change BEFORE into AFTER

#### Before

```
 Stacks[?contains(StackName, 'STRING_A'||'STRING_B')]
```

#### After

```
 Stacks[? (contains(StackName, 'STRING_A') || contains(StackName, 'STRING_B')) ]
```